# T-SQL: How to check if two UTC Dates are on same calendar day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, timezone, utc

I have two DateTimes that are stored in UTC.  How can I tell if they are both on the same calendar date?

The DateDiff method that I found in similar SO questions:

```
where datediff(day, date1, date2) = 0
```

Seems to only be correct when date1 and date2 are in local time.

My current solution is to convert each to localtime, then the do the datediff compare.  But is there any other way to do this without converting to local time?  I thought about subtracting the hours and checking if the result is < 24, but I don't know if I want to try that (might get it wrong).

Thanks!

Comment: There is another way to do without converting but it will be complex step. The simple way to do is to do it in standard time and convert to different time that you want.

Comment: What's the column type of `date1` and `date2`?  datetimeoffset?

Comment: `datetime` and `datetime2` have no concept of time zone, so your question does not make sense as phrased...